# Jenkins not able to run soapUI test: No test to run

Tags: jenkins, testing, maven-2, soapui

I am running SoapUI test from Jenkins.
I have placed my soapui-project.xml file placed in same directory where my pom.xml is placed which is in master in bitbucket. Jenkins is able to pick all changes in my pom.xml. but not running tests.
Jenkin log says **"no test to run"**

I tried adding source and placing my soapui-project.xml file in src/main/resources keeping below properties.

```
<sourceDirectory>src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>src/main/resources</testSourceDirectory>
```

but behavior not changed.

my pom.xml is as below

```
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>Test soapui</name>
    <groupId>RestCountriesInfo</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.example.soapuitests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>SOAPUITesting</description>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <build>
           <!-- <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/main/resources</testSourceDirectory>
   -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.0</version>
 <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                           <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
                           <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
                           <version>1.2.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>RestCountriesInfo</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>RestCountriesInfo-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                            <outputFolder>src/main/resources/report</outputFolder>
                            <testSuite>DEV</testSuite>
                            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                            <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                            <printReport>true</printReport>
                            <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                       
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here are Jenkins logs

```
Posting build status of INPROGRESS to SWC Bitbucket for commit id [d95035dda15d279d5622478d8dbd178591e1f66a] and ref 'refs/heads/master'
Failed to post build status, additional information: timeout
[API_TEST] $ /opt/maven/bin/mvn clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------< RestCountriesInfo:com.example.soapuitests >--------------
[INFO] Building Test soapui 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ com.example.soapuitests ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ com.example.soapuitests ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ com.example.soapuitests ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ com.example.soapuitests ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /opt/jenkins/workspace/Feature/Dev/API_TEST/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ com.example.soapuitests ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ com.example.soapuitests ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.454 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-29T12:47:34+11:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea why Jenkins not able to execute my tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice in your log output that the `soapui-maven-plugin` never got run.

You have two options:

1. In Jenkins you can specify the target phase: `com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.5.0:test`, as per [official documentation](https://www.soapui.org/docs/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x/#2-Running-Tests). But as you can see this contains the plugin version in the command, which is probably undesirable.
2. You can add a `<phase>` that you want to run the soapui plugin in; probably `test`. This goes in your `<configuration>` block. Note that `<goal>` and `<phase>` are not the same thing; they each configure something different, even thought they might have the same target. More information is available in [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Configuring_Build_Plugins).

As a side note, the `<packaging>` for this project is not `jar` - there is no compile phase. It is just `pom`.